# Calculating the average of a parameter estimate

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, estimation

Suppose $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent random variables on $[0,1]$ ~ $\beta(\alpha,\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a positive parameter.

A program generates $10000$ random samples of size $10$ and estimates $\alpha$ with the MLE. Find the average of the $10000$ estimates.

I'm not even sure where to begin, particularly on the line 'sample of size $10$;' aren't the random variables taken from  $[0,1]$? Where does the $10$ come from?

Comment: A particular sample of size $10$ draws $10$ values from the beta distribution, and so - as you say - each of the $10$ values is in $[0,1]$; a single $\hat\alpha$ is then estimated from these $10$ sample values.  The process is repeated another $9999$ times so you have $10000$ $\hat\alpha$ estimates.  You are being asked for the average of these  $10000$ estimates.